# Can I use WP(Write Protect) pin of a USB flash memory controller to prevent tampering with its firmware/stored data?

Tags: pins, hardware, data, firmware, write-protect

I want to have an USB stick that I can make it read-only and insert it in any untrusted PC without risking a silent BadUSB infection.

I was thinking about finding an USB stick that has this WP pin in its controller and DIY mod an external switch to it for Write-Protection.

Do you think it could be possible?

If you have any other simple/cheap solutions to have a 32/64gb device that can be Write-Protected, please let me know.

Comment: Quite a number of SD cards have an external lock switch that forces read only mode. You can get a USB to SD adapter if this would work.

Comment: I'm not sure that the protection of SD cards is enforced or just gracefully ask the OS to comply with it.

Comment: yeah, I think most cards do it in firmware so there's a danger in that. https://superuser.com/questions/581785/how-does-sd-card-write-lock-work seems imply no

Answer (score 0):

The file content, yes provided you can access the NAND write protect pin, prevent the firmware from being replaced with an exploit? generally no, there is normally no provided means to lock the controllers firmware from being modified / replaced, if it exists, it may not be documented.